# How to export GMap configurations?

Tags: views, location, google-maps

I have a View block which renders a map through **GMap** formatter and includes two fields - *Company Name and Address*. When I export it through *features* and try to render it on another system, the map doesn't show up.
I've given custom height and width and some other configurations in GMap under *Configurations > Web Services > GMap*. I think the problem is that the configuration settings for GMap are not being exported with the feature. Is it possible? If so, how to export them?

Here's an image of the View
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found from my seniors that these **configurations** (in this case GMap configurations) are stored in *variables* and **Strongarm** module can be utilised to ***export*** them. After enabling Strongarm module, these variables will be available for exporting under *Strongarm Feature Component* in *Features UI*. The other system/environment on which these variables need to be imported will also need to have Strongarm module enabled.
Though these configurations were exported from my system and imported on the other system properly, the map still didn't show up on the other system, the reason being that the *devel generate* module which we were using to generate content of *Contact* content-type was unable to generate dummy latitude and longitude for the **Location** field (enabled through *Location* module). I entered those latitude and longitude values manually, saved the changes and vola! the map was rendered.
**Note:** In my case, I wasn't using a Google Maps API key so that wasn't a problem.